# Using aiohttp web server with uWSGI

Tags: uwsgi, aiohttp

I have developed a web application using the `aiohttp` module (the `web` part) and haven't encountered any issues so far.

Though, when I try to deploy it to my hosting service (NameCheap), I am asked for the "application startup file" (so I guess it is the Python script I run to start the website, in my case `name.py`) and the "application entry point" (as a hint, I'm given *Setup wsgi callable object for your application*). I'm clueless about that. I've seen some things about how to use uWSGI with Flask and Django but nothing for `aiohttp`.

Is there any way to make things work here, or should I get a VPS instead of a "regular" web hosting service?

Answer (score 1):

aiohttp is not WSGI framework [PEP 333](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-333/) and [PEP 3333](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/) but TCP socket server.

I know nothing about NameCheap hosting, sorry. [aiohttp deployment page](http://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/deployment.html) provides basic information about aiohttp server deployment.

Comment: The instructions on that page are frankly very complicated for anybody used to deploying on places like Heroku, and even on Digital Ocean you'd have to really know what you're doing to deploy aiohttp there. Please consider updating using a real world hosting example such as AWS, Heroku, Azure, etc.